# How do I check the uniform convergence of this sequence of functions?

Tags: calculus

How do I find the uniform convergence of the sequence $f_n(x) =  \begin{cases} 
      \frac{x+nx+1}{n} ,& n-1< x < n \\
       x  ,& \text{otherwise}
   \end{cases}
$.

Comment: Do you mean "How do I _prove_ the uniform convergence..."?

Comment: How do I $check$ for uniform convergence